# Remove old attribute code

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, sql

This is my first time asking a question on the forum whereas I've found many answers before I haven't been able to find an answer to the following:

I am working for an online store and have been working with configurable products, creating attributes and so on. The problem came up when I had created an attribute for a product and everything was fine until I deleted the attribute before disassociating it from the product itself. Now I have quite a few products that are crashing the store when I enable them as the old attribute code is still being associated with these products.

I was able to find on Stack that this is what is causing it and have found the errant attribute code. I tried recreating the old attribute but obviously it assigns a new code.

I used Magento store Manager CustomSQL to discover the attribute code but it wont let me change anything or delete.

My question: How can I delete the old attribute code from the database?

Comment: After deleting the attribute you should re-index, did that not clear it out?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Fabian for your answer.

This is the solution I found:

It turns out that it was a problem with orphaned attributes. The deleted attribute's association to the products was still in the catalog_product_super_attribute database. Which was causing the crash.

Based on other answers to other questions in the forum this is the solution I found:
The first 2 are from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942701/getid-on-a-non-object

The 3rd comes from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291572/in-magento-is-there-a-way-to-remove-attribute-from-configurable-product-after-a

1. I used this SQL command

   > select * from catalog_product_super_attribute where product_id=productid

   to identify the attributes associated with the products
2. I then used

   > select attribute_id,attribute_code from eav_attribute where
   >   attribute_id=ID or attribute_id=id

   to show the name associated with ID to verify I found the correct
   attribute.
3. Lastly this command

   > DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute WHERE attribute_id =ID

   to remove the problem orphaned attribute ID

Comment: if this is now working then feel free to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as you have a problem with your database.

Theoretically all entries in catalog_product_entity_* should be deleted, because they all have a foreign key on the eav_attribute.

You should check, whether theses foreign keys exists.

What you can try is query the different catalog_product_entity_* tables and check for entries which doesn't have any representation in eav_attribute, delete these entries.